# Gson: JsonSyntaxException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING

Tags: java, json, hashmap, gson

I am trying to convert a JSON String into a HashMap. Here is some of my code:

```
public static void createSimpleAppointment(String json){
try
    {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    HashMap<String,String> data = new HashMap<String,String>();
    data = gson.fromJson(json, data.getClass());
```

The exception is being thrown on the last of those lines (where I set data).

The JSON String is

> {"body": "body", "startDate": "2014-05-30 11:00:00", "endDate": "2014-05-30 12:00:00", "location": "location", "subject": "subject!"}

The exception I get is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
>       at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoader.java:58)
>   Caused by: com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:815)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:768)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:717)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:689)
>       at ews.calendar.Calendar.createSimpleAppointment(Calendar.java:70)
>       at ews.main.gateway.Main.main(Main.java:34)
>       ... 5 more
>   Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 3
>       at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:374)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:183)
>       at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
>       at com.google.gson.Gson.fromJson(Gson.java:803)
>       ... 10 more

Answer (score 3):

You can convert the JSON string into Java POJO class as well. The name of instance member in POJO class should be exactly same (*case-sensitive*) as defined in JSON string.

> You don't need to convert the date string to date object that is handled by [GsonBuilder#setDateFormat()](http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/GsonBuilder.html#setPrettyPrinting%28%29) method by default.

Sample code:

```
class MyJSONObject {
    private String body;
    private Date startDate;
    private Date endDate;
    private String location;
    private String subject;
    // getter & setter
}

// convert json string to MyJSONObject 
MyJSONObject data = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
                              .create().fromJson(jsonString, MyJSONObject.class);

// pretty printing of JSON string back from POJO class object
System.out.println(new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create().toJson(data));
```

output:

```
{
    "body": "body",
    "startDate": "May 30, 2014 11:00:00 AM",
    "endDate": "May 30, 2014 12:00:00 PM",
    "location": "location",
    "subject": "subject!"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't get the exception you are reporting with Gson 2.2.4, but you should start using `TypeToken`s for generic types.

```
HashMap<String, String> data = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<HashMap<String, String>>() {}.getType());
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a Map within a class that was to be json-ed and the same error as described above:

```
public class Setting implements Serializable {
private Map<Key, Double> keyToValue = new HashMap<>();

// other fields, setters and getters...

public Map<Key, Double> getKeyToValue() {
        return keyToValue;
    }
public void setKeyToValue(Map<PlantKey, Double> keyToValue) {
        this.keyToValue = keyToValue;
    }
}
```

I had to use the following to make it work:

```
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.enableComplexMapKeySerialization();
builder.create();
```

Source: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/478

Answer (score 0):

The error can be a bit misleading - in my case it was a missing `Deserializer` for `LocalDateTime` and it failed on the first Date.